# Redirect to root or another page when page not found rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm forwarding traffic from another site and linking using the title, in some cases the titles don't match. right now, users get:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

I want to create a simple redirect to home page when an user goes to a page that doesn't exist.

for example: mysite.com/shows/awesome-show/episodes/doesnt-exist

Tried:

```
  match '*a', :to => 'home#index'
```

Wondering if there's a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails should automatically have set up `404.html`, `422.html`, `500.html` files in your app's `public` folder just for this purpose. They're also pre-populated with text and styles. If you just modify those it should work.